# Implementing tree data structure for frontend components

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm trying to plan out a simple web app. A user is presented with a question that has two or three possible answers. Depending on their answer, they're taken to another question.

i.e.

```
                                            ChoiceC
               ChoiceA ---> Question 2 ---> ChoiceD
Question 1 -->                              
               ChoiceB ---> Question 3 ---> ChoiceE
                                            ChoiceF
```

This seems to me a like a tree, where each question and answer is a node, and depending on what path you go down, you're exposed to a specific set of other questions/answers.

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this with reusable React components. I could potentially create a component for each question, but that doesn't seem like good practice. Does anyone have any experience building these sorts of 'choose-your-own-adventure' style questionnaires?

Comment: do the nesting of same component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that saves for every answer what the next question is.
In your case an entry could be [ChoiceA, Question2]. In your program you can then story a variable *current_question* that gets updated based on your map.

This solution may only be insufficient if the same answer can arise in different contexts and lead to different outcomes. In this case maybe should be a question/answer-pair that determines what comes next.

If you really want to overkill your problem, you can implement a directed labeled graph. The questions would be the nodes in this case and the edge-labels are your answers which lead to the next question/node.

The most pragmatic solution would of course be to don't use a datastructure at all and just stack if-else. This is not scalable though.

Comment: This is super helpful. As each question obviously has a particular set of choices/answers, should I be mapping in that direction as well? Each question potentially has a few answers. Do you know if I can map an array to a value, i.e. ['Question2', ['ChoiceC', 'ChoiceD']]?

Comment: I don't know JavaScript, but look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map. It seems to my that it even supports functions as values, so why not arrays, I guess? You can just try to use an array and see if it works. Generally such a kind of object is called "multimap", search for it, maybe you find it elsewhere if it is not supported natively.

Comment: And also consider wrapping the choices as a set, not as an array. This way you can add choices as you go.